# AWS Spot Instances created with Terraform Spot-fleet request does not return public_ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am provisioning the AWS Spot-fleet using Terraform.

The Spot-fleet gets provisioned successfully but the issue comes when I try to use ssh to connect to the instance so that I can run my Node.js App on it (pre-installed on the AMI). I am not able to retrieve the public_ip address of the instances which has been provisioned.

My request looks like this:

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.aws_region}"
}

resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "spot_fleet" {
  iam_fleet_role                      = "${var.iam_fleet_role}"
  spot_price                          = "${var.spot_price}"
  allocation_strategy                 = "${var.allocation_strategy}"
  target_capacity                     = "${var.target_capacity}"
  terminate_instances_with_expiration = "${var.terminate_instances_with_expiration}"
  valid_until                         = "${var.valid_until}"
  wait_for_fulfillment                = "${var.wait_for_fulfillment}"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type          = "${var.instance_type}"
    key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
    ami                    = "${var.ami}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_id}"]

    root_block_device {
      volume_size = "${var.volume_size}"
      volume_type = "${var.volume_type}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "cd my-app",
      "npm install",
      "npm start",
    ]

    connection {
      host        = "${self.public_ip}"
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("my-secret.pem")}"
      timeout     = "2m"
      agent       = false
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error which I get:

```
Error applying plan:

 1 error(s) occurred:

  * aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_fleet: 1 error(s) occurred:

  * Resource 'aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_fleet' does not have attribute 'public_ip' for variable 'aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_fleet.0.public_ip'
```

The provisioned spot instances as such do have the Public IP Address and I am able to see it in AWS Console.

I am also able to SSH into the instance using Terminal.

Comment: Forgot to add following:
1. The provisioned spot instances as such do have the Public IP Address and I am able to see it in AWS Console.
2. I am also able to SSH into the instance using Terminal.

Comment: The `aws_spot_fleet_request` doesn't export any attributes about the instances it creates at all other than the inputted attributes so this isn't going to work for you. In your case you're probably fine to use straight spot instances (with the `aws_spot_instance_request` resource) because you probably don't need the flexibility of the instance types you get with spot fleets.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, @ydaetskcoR! The use-case involves processing large files and is compute intensive. For now I guess it should be okay to use `aws_spot_instance_request` instead of `aws_spot_fleet_request`. Really appreciate you taking out time for replying!

Comment: If somebody happens to come on this page searching for this specific issue, a question has been also been asked to the team at Terraform here [link](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1678). Thanks!